# DrawerNavigator - Undefined is a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I run my android app on virtual device, It throws an error `Undefined is not a function`

I have tried to replace "AppDrawerNavigator" to "App" in my code, it solved the problem, but created another one 'Duplicate declaration "App"' error in console. Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigationDrawer />
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigationDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  });
```

**Error**

> undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0, _reactNavigation.DrawerNavigator)({ Home: {screen: _HomeScreen2.default},
>     });)

Answer (score 4):

The `DrawerNavigator` doesn't seem to be in the *named export* in their main exports [file](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/src/react-navigation.js#L50-L55) in `react-navigation@latest`

Instead import it as `createDrawerNavigator`

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but I have got an error  'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State')

Comment: There are some breaking changes in the new version that you can read [here](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/#installation). This error is due to not linking of 
 `react-native-gesture-handler`